# How to get current url in Safari web extension popup window?

Tags: swift, xcode, web, safari

I'm writing the safari web extension and trying to get the current webpage url in the popup.js , but the code does not work .  How to solve the problem ?

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
            <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
            <script  src="jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script  src="qrcode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo">temp</p>
    <strong>Hello World!----gg-</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js :

```
console.log("Hello World!", browser);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;
```